# Remove duplicate rows with certain value in specific column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and I want to remove rows that are duplicated in all columns except one column and choose to keep the ones that are not certain values.

[image]

In above example, 3rd row and 4th row are duplicated for all columns except for col3, so I want to keep one row only. The complicated step is I want to keep 4th row instead of 3rd because 3rd row in col3 is "excluded". In general, I want to only keep the rows(that were duplicated) that do not have "excluded".

My real data frame have lots of duplicated rows and among those 2 rows that are duplicated, one of them is "excluded" for sure.

Below is re-producible ex:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,3,7)
b <- c(4,5,6,6,8)
c <- c("red","green","excluded","orange","excluded")
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Thank you so much!

Update: Or, when removing duplicate, only keep the second observation (4th row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dplyr with some base R should work for this:

```
 library(dplyr) 
 a <- c(1,2,3,3,3,7)
 b <- c(4,5,6,6,6,8)
 c <- c("red","green","brown","excluded","orange","excluded")
 d <- data.frame(a,b,c)

 d <- filter(d, !duplicated(d[,1:2]) | c!="excluded")

Result: 
  a b        c
1 1 4      red
2 2 5    green
3 3 6    brown
4 3 6   orange
5 7 8 excluded
```

The filter will get rid of anything that should be excluded and not duplicated. I added an example of a none unique exclude to your example('brown') to test as well.

Comment: Ok I updated the solution. The duplicated function is used to create a logical vector for the duplicated items and then we keep anything that isn't duplicated or that isn't excluded. I tested on your data and I got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with a loop:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,3,7)
b <- c(4,5,6,6,8)
c <- c("red","green","excluded","orange","excluded")
d<- data.frame(a,b,c)

# Give row indices of duplicated rows (only the second and more occurence are given)
duplicated_rows=which(duplicated(d[c("a","b")]))

to_remove=c()
# Loop over different duplicated rows
for(i in duplicated_rows){
  # Find simmilar rows
  selection=which(d$a==d$a[i] & d$b==d$b[i])
  # Sotre indices of raw in the set of duplicated row whihc are "excluded"
  to_remove=c(to_remove,selection[which(d$c[selection]=="excluded")])
}

# Remove rows
d=d[-to_remove,]

print(d)

> a b       c
> 1 4      red
> 2 2 5   green
> 4 3 6   orange
> 5 7 8  excluded
```

Comment: The code works well for that example. However, I have big data frame (2.6M rows * 35 column) so I want to avoid for loop. Can you propose another way please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility ... I hope it can help :)

```
nquit <- (d %>%
  mutate(code= 1:nrow(d)) %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  mutate(nDuplicate= n()) %>%
  filter(nDuplicate > 1) %>%
  filter(c == "excluded"))$code

e <- d[-nquit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortening the approach by @Klone a bit, another dplyr solution:

```
d %>% mutate(c = factor(c, ordered = TRUE, 
                        levels = c("red", "green", "orange", "excluded"))) %>% # Order the factor variable
  arrange(c) %>% # Sort the data frame so that excluded comes first
  group_by(a, b) %>% # Group by the two columns that determine duplicates
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% # Assign IDs in each group
  filter(id == 1) # Only keep one row in each group
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   a, b [4]
      a     b c           id
  <dbl> <dbl> <ord>    <int>
1     1     4 red          1
2     2     5 green        1
3     3     6 orange       1
4     7     8 excluded     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit at the end of the question:

> Update: Or, when removing duplicate, only keep the second observation (4th row).

note that, in case the ordering of the rows by `col3` determines that the *row to keep is always the last one* among the duplicate records, you can simply set `fromLast=TRUE` in the `duplicated()` function to request that rows should be flagged as duplicates *starting the duplicate count from the last one found* for each duplicate group.

Using a slightly modified version of your data (where I added more duplicate groups to better show that the process works in a more general case):

```
a <- c(1,1,2,3,3,3,7)
b <- c(4,4,5,6,6,6,8)
c <- c("excluded", "red","green","excluded", "excluded","orange","excluded")
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)

  a b        c
1 1 4 excluded
2 1 4      red
3 2 5    green
4 3 6 excluded
5 3 6 excluded
6 3 6   orange
7 7 8 excluded
```

using:

```
ind2remove = duplicated(d[,c("a", "b")], fromLast=TRUE)
(d_noduplicates = d[!ind2remove,])
```

we get:

```
  a b        c
2 1 4      red
3 2 5    green
6 3 6   orange
7 7 8 excluded
```

Note that this doesn't require the rows in each duplicate group to be all together in the original data. The only important thing is that you want to *keep the record showing up last in the data* from each duplicate group.